# Removing redundant data from collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, collections

From the database i am getting a list of collection which has repetitive data 
for eg - total length of the List is 4 which has elements like

```
Item[0].Id  9
Item[1].Id  10
Item[2].id  9
Item[3].id  10
```

i want the collection to be of length 2 having both the Id as

```
Item[0].Id  9, 10
Item[1].Id  9,10
```

Comment: Have a look at [c# - Linq Distinct on particular Property](http://stackoverflow.com/a/489421/1466627).

Comment: Your question is unclear. What about `Item[2]` and `Item[3]`? What is your criterion for grouping values 9,10 against `Item[0]`?

Comment: what exactly i want is dont add the duplicate records in item list

Comment: Very unclear question. Separate code from potential "explanation" or "console output"....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear, so I'm going to take your comment that you don't want duplicates in your item collection as the question.  If this is indeed accurate then I can think of two possible solutions: one is to filter duplicates when you get the data from the database, and the other is to enforce this in your c# code.

It won't alter the output to two integers comma separated as you've put in your example, but judging from your later comments this isn't what you're trying to do.

**SQL Solution**
You could use distinct if you're using sql to retrieve the data, for example:

```
select id from aTable
```

becomes:

```
select distinct id from aTable
```

**C# Collection Solution**
You could use the inbuilt functions of an arraylist, for example, to prevent duplicates:

```
var data = new int[4];
data[0] = 9;
data[1] = 9;
data[2] = 10;
data[3] = 10;

var item = new ArrayList();

foreach (int i in data)
    if (!item.Contains(i)) item.Add(i);
```

I hope one of these solves your problem!  Best of luck!